# Finding Average of Daily Sessions with a Static Max Date and Min Date

Tags: php, mysql, self-join

PHP 5.X, MySQL 5.7.15

Got data grouped by Day of the week to provide an average count of sessions on a daily use using a Max Date and Min Date. The Max and Min Date is being applied to the Day of the Week in this scenario, which causes the number of weeks to be different for each case.

The query that built these results is defined as **Query 1** below. Essentially the Information in the last 4 columns should be static, I accomplished this using **SELF JOIN**, which is detailed below. In that example the **session_count** exploded since I am only working in a dev environment.

So what went wrong and why?

```
  session_count | weekday | maxDate             |minDate              | numOfDayDiff| numOfWeeks
'29'            | 'Friday'|'2017-03-10 12:16:47'|'2016-08-12 12:31:28'| '210'       | '30'
'26'            |'Monday' |'2017-03-06 17:10:59'|'2016-08-08 14:31:16'| '210'       | '30'
'6'            |'Saturday'|'2017-03-04 23:26:12'|'2016-08-20 23:10:47'| '196'       | '28'
'10'            |'Sunday' |'2017-03-12 18:28:51'|'2016-08-14 16:26:30'| '210'       | '30'
'22'           |'Thursday'|'2017-03-09 15:45:27'|'2016-06-30 12:42:19'| '252'       | '36'
'22'            |'Tuesday'|'2017-03-21 15:00:08'|'2016-06-28 19:51:21'| '266'       | '38'
'22'          |'Wednesday'|'2017-03-01 23:57:34'|'2016-07-06 16:17:39'| '238'       | '34'
```

I want the max date and min date to be static. I have tried to use w3schools explanation of [Self JOIN Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp)

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1 T1, table1 T2
WHERE condition;
```

I tried applying this query, the maxDate, minDate, numDaysDiff and numOfWeeks were consistent with the values for the highest number of weeks above, but the stats for the **session_count** exploded.

Here is **Query 1** which obtained the table above:

```
SELECT
CEIL(COUNT(ss.session_id) / (FLOOR (DATEDIFF(MAX(ss.date),MIN(ss.date))/7))) as session_count,
DAYNAME((ss.date)) as weekday,
MAX(ss.date) as maxDate,
MIN(ss.date) as minDate,
DATEDIFF(MAX(ss.date),MIN(ss.date)) as numOfDayDiff,
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MAX(ss.date),MIN(ss.date))/7) as numOfWeeks
FROM  session ss
JOIN user u ON ss.user = u.id
JOIN account a on u.account = a.id
WHERE a.isTest=false
GROUP BY weekday
ORDER BY weekday;
```

Here is **Q-2** modified using the **SELF JOIN** syntax followed with the output table:

```
SELECT
CEIL(COUNT(ss.session_id) / (FLOOR (DATEDIFF(MAX(xx.date),MIN(xx.date))/7))) as session_count,
DAYNAME((ss.date)) as weekday,
MAX(xx.date) as maxDate,
MIN(xx.date) as minDate,
DATEDIFF(MAX(xx.date),MIN(xx.date)) as numOfDayDiff,
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MAX(xx.date),MIN(xx.date))/7) as numOfWeeks
FROM  session xx, session ss
JOIN user u ON ss.user = u.id
JOIN account a on u.account = a.id
WHERE a.isTest=false
GROUP BY weekday
ORDER BY weekday;
```

Results are:

```
session_count | weekday | maxDate             |minDate              | numOfDayDiff| numOfWeeks
99357         |Friday   |2017-03-21 15:00:08  |2016-06-28 19:51:21  |266          |38
88062         |Monday   |2017-03-21 15:00:08  |2016-06-28 19:51:21  |266          |38
16829         |Saturday |2017-03-21 15:00:08  |2016-06-28 19:51:21  |266          |38
32505         |Sunday   |2017-03-21 15:00:08  |2016-06-28 19:51:21  |266          |38
90136         |Thursday |2017-03-21 15:00:08  |2016-06-28 19:51:21  |266          |38
94516         |Tuesday  |2017-03-21 15:00:08  |2016-06-28 19:51:21  |266          |38
83451         |Wednesday|2017-03-21 15:00:08  |2016-06-28 19:51:21  |266          |38
```

Can anyone please advise me how I have made an error? I am going to see if I can create a mysql fiddle to attach here as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep stress off the database I have decided to use a modified version of  **Query 1** and use the results to determine which one has the greatest number of weeks and dividing the count by the number of weeks in the php.

Here is the modified **Query 1**

```
SELECT
COUNT(ss.session_id) as session_count,
DAYNAME((ss.date)) as weekday,
MAX(ss.date) as maxDate,
MIN(ss.date) as minDate,
CEIL(DATEDIFF(MAX(ss.date),MIN(ss.date))/7) as numOfWeeks
FROM  session ss
JOIN user u ON ss.user = u.id
JOIN account a on u.account = a.id
WHERE a.isTest=false
GROUP BY weekday
ORDER BY weekday;

session_count | weekday | maxDate            | minDate           | numOfWeeks
2017          | Friday  |2017-03-17 23:39:56 |2016-09-09 01:06:36|  27
1908          | Monday  |2017-03-20 23:59:53 |2016-09-12 14:52:29|  27
943           | Saturday|2017-03-18 23:39:14 |2016-09-17 14:49:56|  26
825           | Sunday  |2017-03-19 23:56:37 |2016-09-18 22:28:45|  26
2429          | Thursday|2017-03-16 23:51:23 |2016-09-08 12:02:54|  27
2341          | Tuesday |2017-03-21 23:52:20 |2016-09-06 12:06:39|  28
2569          |Wednesday|2017-03-22 17:03:16 |2016-09-07 02:43:10|  28
```

**Note** Data Differs Due to Different Database.